# How do I fix a Postgres 12 Error: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, set-returning-functions, postgresql-12

I just updated my Postres from 9.1 to 12 and I'm now getting this error message from a specific query:

```
SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 7 ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE LINE 17: generate_series(start_date, ^ HINT: You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

The actual query generating that error is is part of a much larger on but the actual lines are:

```
CASE
    WHEN num_payments > 1 THEN
        generate_series(start_date, start_date + ((payment_interval*(num_payments-1)) || payment_interval2)::interval, (payment_interval::text || payment_interval2)::interval)::date
    ELSE
        start_date
END
```

Being the first time seeing this message, I have no idea what this entails. How do I `move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item` as the error message hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I wasn't able to use the `LATERAL` since it just generated other syntactic error messages (I'll have to work on that on the long run). So I was able to solve my issue by simply just selecting all values then moving the `CASE` higher up in the query so that the `generate_series()` is not inside a case statement:

```
SELECT other_columns, 
       CASE
           WHEN num_payments > 1 THEN date_2 ELSE date_1
       END AS start_date
FROM(
       SELECT other_columns, 
              start_date AS date_1,
              generate_series(start_date, start_date + ((payment_interval*(num_payments-1)) || payment_interval2)::interval, (payment_interval::text || payment_interval2)::interval)::date AS date_2
       FROM(
           -- INNER QUERY
       )a
)b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called a "Lateral Join" -- basically it is a calculated column that is "cross joined" to your current query.

Use it like this:

```
SELECT MY_LATERAL,
     -- etc other columns 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
  LATERAL (CASE
           WHEN num_payments > 1 THEN
             generate_series(start_date, start_date + ((payment_interval*(num_payments-1)) || payment_interval2)::interval, (payment_interval::text || payment_interval2)::interval)::date
           ELSE start_date
           END) AS MY_LATERAL
```

Documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html section 7.2.1.5